# An error list when putting icons to buttons (netbeans)

Tags: java, netbeans, icons

I get this huge set of errors when I'm trying to add icons to a button in Netbeans JFrame:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:205)
at furnituremanagementsystem.menu.initComponents(menu.java:86)
at furnituremanagementsystem.menu.<init>(menu.java:17)
at furnituremanagementsystem.menu$12.run(menu.java:273)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:727)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

The thing is it always happen the SECOND time I'm trying to add an icon. Can you guys explain what this error(s) means?
Thank you.
 PS Button Codes:

```
jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();

jButton5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N

jButton5.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));

jButton5.setIcon(new       javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/furnituremanagementsystem/user-group-icon9878.png"))); // NOI18N

jButton5.setText("Customer");

jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
}
```

});

```
 jPanel1.add(jButton5, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(60, 170, 230, -1));
```

Comment: I'm not using a code at all actually. It is auto-generated when I do it via netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the first line of the error, it says `NullPointerException`. That usually measn you are trying to call a method on a null pointer. The rest of the error is a stack trace of the moment the error occurred. Here it looks like It happened at line 205 in ImageIcon, which is a constructor for `ImageIcon` that looks like this:

```
public ImageIcon (URL location) {
    this(location, location.toExternalForm()); // line 205
}
```

As far as I can tell, you are probably passing in a null URL object to this constructor in your `furnituremanagementsystem.menu.initComponents()` method. That is throwing a null pointer exception when this line tries to use it by calling `toExternalForm()` on it.

Assuming line 86 is the line where you are constructing the ImageIcon object, it looks like `getResource()` is not finding anything by the name given, causing it to return null. You should try to figure out if the call to `getResource()` is returning null, or a URL object. If it's returning null, figure out why it can't find that resource.

FYI: That's actually only 1 error. It looks like a lot because you get a stack trace along with it.

Comment: But I didn't do any type of coding at all. I simply used the options in netbeans to do it for me. At first it worked. But the second icon button brings these errors.

Comment: Just because netbeans generated it for you doesn't mean it's 100% correct.